# NodeJS - Jade - How to print in center of browser

Tags: node.js, pug

I need to print a text in browser center of a new line like below:

```
                           Welcome to ALERT SYSTEM






                                Bus Number : X11 
                                Location   : 1
```

My JADE template is like below:

```
extends layout

block content

  p
     |                                                      Welcome to #{title}
     |   <br/>                                                                             
     |   <br/>                                                                            
     |   <br/>                                                                              
     |   <br/>                                                                              
     |   <br/>                                                                             
     |   <br/>                                                                             
     |   <br/>                                                                             
     |   <br/>                                                                             
     |                                                      Bus Number :  #{bus_no}
     |                                                      Location   :  #{location}
```

But It does not comes. The output in browser is like below:

```
Welcome to ALERT SYSTEM

Welcome to Alert System Bus Number : X11 Location : 1
```

How can I code in Jade Template to display in format as desied?

Answer (score 1):

first of all: what you want to show in the browser doesn't look like a HTML file.
It's look like an ASCI text.

If you want to do this in HTML you should use the `<pre>` tag, because usually multiple whitespaces are shown in browsers only as one whitespace.

Otherwise you should use CSS to style and center your content!

But here, the ASCI solution in HTML:

```
<pre>
                       Welcome to ALERT SYSTEM






                            Bus Number : X11 
                            Location   : 1
</pre>
```

and here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BbrM6/

In Jade you need this:

```
pre.
  &nbsp;                        Welcome to ALERT SYSTEM






                                Bus Number : X11 
                                Location   : 1
```

You neeed the `&nbsp;` because otherwise Jade skip the whitespaces like the browser do it.
Alternatively you can use the **pipe** instead of the **dot** notation.

But for empty lines you need to put a whitespace after the pipe, otherwise you get an error.

```
pre
  | plain text
  | the next line will fail because there is no content
  |
  | put a whitespace in the line above to fix the syntax error
```